# Economics of Yeshivas

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

In economics we have used producer theory to analyse businesses which assumes the goal of a firm is profit maximisation. Economic literature has always referred to the goal of a education is to train people to become productive.

obviously the goal of the yeshiva is not job training. What is the goal of a yeshiva?

Comment: Is the goal of medical study economics? Is that the goal of the study of physics? Do I need to go on? I see by your username and all your questions you have a very limited world view, but this one is beyond the pale.

Comment: @user6591 I think you misread the question. the end goal of secular education is integration into the work force. what is the end goal of a yeshiva  period. Is there an end goal?

Comment: Each yeshiva can have its own goal. This does not seem very answerable. A much better question, IMHO would be what the point of Torah study is. (It might be a dupe, however).

Comment: @user6591  sorry my interest in halachic pricing offends you.

Comment: What's the sentence win haolam Nixon ela bishvil chanina beni says?

Answer (score 1):

the goal of a yeshiva is not to make money but to study torah.

The reason is that Torah study leads to following it "if you will walk in My statutes.." (Lev.26:3) (which refers to torah study. see Rashi there).

and lack of torah study leads to abandonment of it and God (see Lev.26:14): "But if you do not listen to Me and do not perform all these commandments", which refers to Torah study (Rashi), then the cascade of abandoning everything follows as explained there.

See also the Path of the Just where he explains the Baraitha "Torah leads to watchfulness..."

and in [ch.5](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=8&e=0)

> For the Creator, blessed be He, who created the evil inclination also
>   created the torah as its antidote as our sages of blessed memory have
>   stated: "I have created the evil inclination, and I have created the
>   torah as its antidote" (Kidushin 30b).

Hence, to us torah study is of utmost importance. For it produces torah observant Jews and the lack of it produces Jews who drop out of Judaism. In the past few centuries, especially where Jews left the ghettos and mingled with non-Jews, it became essential to strengthen this area and thus the [yeshiva movement](http://www.jewishhistory.org/the-volozhin-revolution/) was started 200 years ago.